# Sony Xperia S destroys last Activity instead of pause

Tags: android, image, android-intent, sony-xperia

trying to open the Image Gallery so the user can pick an image via:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
myActivity.startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, LoadImageIntentID);
```

Most devices this works great, but on the Sony Xperia S, the activity I used to wait for the "onActivityResult" event is destroyed instead of paused like every other device.  What is going on?

Comment: check developer option and make sure don't keep activity not checked

Comment: Looks like that was it, tnx.